# Yesod - Persistent - ODBC issue

Tags: sql, haskell, yesod

My relevant models:

```
ProductCharacteristic
  productInstance ProductInstanceId sql=productInstanceId
  characteristicInstance CharacteristicInstanceId sql=characteristicInstanceId
  deriving Show

Product
  codePrefix Text
  defaultPrice Double
  defaultBuyingPrice Double
  name Text
  obs Text
  disabled Bool
  deriving Show

ProductInstance
  product ProductId sql=productId
  code Text
  barCode Text
  price Double
  buyingPrice Double
  proportional Bool
  obs Text
  disabled Bool
  deriving Show
```

Now my `Esqueleto` expression:

```
f' :: Handler [(Entity ProductInstance, Entity Product, Entity ProductCharacteristic)]
f' = runDB
   $ E.select
   $ E.from $ \(pi `E.InnerJoin` p `E.InnerJoin` pc) -> do
     E.on $ pi ^. ProductInstanceProduct E.==. p ^. ProductId
     E.on $ pc ^. ProductCharacteristicProductInstance E.==. pi ^. ProductInstanceId
     return ( pi, p, pc)
```

The code I showed generated the following select instruction (which is wrong):

```
SELECT `ProductInstance`.`id`, `ProductInstance`.`productId`, `ProductInstance`.`code`, `ProductInstance`.`barCode`, `ProductInstance`.`price`, `ProductInstance`.`buyingPrice`, `ProductInstance`.`proportional`, `ProductInstance`.`obs`, `ProductInstance`.`disabled`, `Product`.`id`, `Product`.`codePrefix`, `Product`.`defaultPrice`, `Product`.`defaultBuyingPrice`, `Product`.`name`, `Product`.`obs`, `Product`.`disabled`, `ProductCharacteristic`.`id`, `ProductCharacteristic`.`productInstanceId`, `ProductCharacteristic`.`characteristicInstanceId`
FROM `ProductInstance` INNER JOIN `Product` ON `ProductCharacteristic`.`productInstanceId` = `ProductInstance`.`id` INNER JOIN `ProductCharacteristic` ON `ProductInstance`.`productId` = `Product`.`id`;
```

It is flipping the `on` clause in the `JOIN`!! How can I make a workaround???

The correct select instruction should be:

```
SELECT `ProductInstance`.`id`, `ProductInstance`.`productId`, `ProductInstance`.`code`, `ProductInstance`.`barCode`, `ProductInstance`.`price`, `ProductInstance`.`buyingPrice`, `ProductInstance`.`proportional`, `ProductInstance`.`obs`, `ProductInstance`.`disabled`, `Product`.`id`, `Product`.`codePrefix`, `Product`.`defaultPrice`, `Product`.`defaultBuyingPrice`, `Product`.`name`, `Product`.`obs`, `Product`.`disabled`, `ProductCharacteristic`.`id`, `ProductCharacteristic`.`productInstanceId`, `ProductCharacteristic`.`characteristicInstanceId`
FROM `ProductInstance` INNER JOIN `Product` ON `ProductInstance`.`productId` = `Product`.`id` INNER JOIN `ProductCharacteristic` ON `ProductCharacteristic`.`productInstanceId` = `ProductInstance`.`id`;
```

Comment: Flipping the `on` clauses in the `Esqueleto` expression created a valid select instruction, but I think it is a bug anyway.